# Find date sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find the maximum sequence of days by customer in my data. I want to understand what is the max sequence of days that specific customer made. If someone enter to my app in the 25/8/16 AND 26/08/16 AND 27/08/16 AND 01/09/16 AND 02/09/16 - The max sequence will be 3 days (25,26,27).

In the end (The output) I want to get two fields: custid | MaxDaySequence

I have the following fields in my data table: custid | orderdate(timestemp)

For exmple:

```
custid  orderdate
1   25/08/2007
1   03/10/2007
1   13/10/2007
1   15/01/2008
1   16/03/2008
1   09/04/2008
2   18/09/2006
2   08/08/2007
2   28/11/2007
2   04/03/2008
3   27/11/2006
3   15/04/2007
3   13/05/2007
3   19/06/2007
3   22/09/2007
3   25/09/2007
3   28/01/2008
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 2014.

Thanks

---

Trying:

```
select custid, max(num_days) as longest 
from ( 
       select custid,rn, count (*) as num_days 
       from (
           select custid, date(orderdate), 
                  cast (row_number() over (partition by custid order by date(orderdate)) as varchar(5)) as rn 
           from table_
       ) x group by custid, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL rn|| ' day'
 ) y group by custid
```

Comment: Trying: 

select custid, max(num_days) as longest
from (
    select custid,rn, count (*)  as num_days
    from (select custid, date(orderdate), cast (row_number() over (partition by custid order by date(orderdate)) as varchar(5)) as rn from table_) x
    

    group by custid, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL rn|| ' day') y
    
group by custid

Comment: There is no such thing as "Postgres 2014". The current version is 9.6. What does `select version()` show you?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT custid, max( abc ) as max_sequence_of_days
FROM (
  SELECT custid, yy, count(*) abc
  FROM (
    SELECT * ,
          SUM( xx ) OVER (partition by custid order by orderdate ) yy
    FROM (
      select * ,
          CASE WHEN 
              orderdate - lag( orderdate ) over (partition by custid order by orderdate ) 
              <= 1
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END xx
      from mytable
    ) x
  ) z
  GROUP BY custid, yy
) q
GROUP BY custid
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00422/11

---

===== EDIT ===========

---

> Got "operator does not exist: interval <= integer"

This means that `orderdate` column is of type `timestamp`, not `date`.
In this case you need to use `<= interval '1' day` condition instead of `<= 1`:
Please see this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html to learn more about date arithmetic in PostgreSQL

Please see this demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7c2200/2

```
SELECT custid, max( abc ) as max_sequence_of_days
FROM (
  SELECT custid, yy, count(*) abc
  FROM (
    SELECT * ,
          SUM( xx ) OVER (partition by custid order by orderdate ) yy
    FROM (
      select * ,
          CASE WHEN 
              orderdate - lag( orderdate ) over (partition by custid order by orderdate ) 
              <= interval '1' day
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END xx
      from mytable
    ) x
  ) z
  GROUP BY custid, yy
) q
GROUP BY custid
```

Comment: Thanks!!

Got "operator does not exist: interval <= integer"
Tried to do cast as int on the interval but got '1' as max on every custid

Comment: I've updated the answer. This error means that `orderdate` column is a timestamp, not a date.